# C# view SQL results in command line

Tags: c#

I have looked around stack overflow and the various solutions to this problem aren't working for me. I don't get an error but no results are returning. It just waits for me to press enter and then kills the program. I would expect four rows to return

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Hello
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        String connectionString = "Data Source= myServer; Initial Catalog= myDatabaseName;        Integrated Security=SSPI;";

        System.Console.WriteLine(connectionString);

        //set up by connection
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        try
        {
            myConnection.Open();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }

        //print the connection
        System.Console.WriteLine(myConnection);

        //try looking 
        List<int> productID = new List<int>();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select productID from product", myConnection);
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
           // var myString = reader.GetString(0);
            productID.Add(Convert.ToInt32(reader["productID"].ToString()));
        }

        System.Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Have you used a debugger to look at the contents of productId? I ask because you're not actually printing anything out, or doing anything that would indicate 'something happened'.

Comment: @SteveG, I am! Autos, Locals, and Watch1 show nothing. Error list shows nothing either. Is my connection maybe not working and failing silently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might recommend `Console.WriteLine(reader["productID"].ToString())` inside of the while loop.  If you don't write to the console, don't expect there to be anything.

Comment: @KillerSmalls if that was the answer, you should accept it as the answer to thank him for helping you.

Answer (score 1):

What are you expecting?  You didn't even print the record to Console.  Records are returned, but they're hiding in memory :)

Example, add following before `ReadLine()` call:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, productID));
```